# How this code can be refactored to improve readability?

Tags: javascript, readability

Can anyone tell me how can I improve the code to make it more readable?

```
t = t.replace(/Whatsapp\.API\./, '').replace(/\s/g, '');
```

Any suggestions would be helpful :)

Please leave a comment for down-voting.

Comment: No need for regex for the second - you can use `.replaceAll(' ', '')`.

Comment: thank you. any other suggestions?

Comment: @Al.G. [`String.replaceAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll#Browser_compatibility) is not yet available in all running environments.

Comment: Good point @axiac

Comment: Since you are replacing both occurrences with `''`, you can use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) using a pipe:  `t.replace(/Whatsapp\.API\.|\s/g , '')`

Comment: I had done that before. but my lead asked me to improve readability so I changed that to the above mentioned code :D

Comment: An alternation is perfectly readable for anyone with elementary knowledge of regex. This regex not even complex.

Answer (score 0):

Add constant names to the REGEXs so you can use anywhere, and make a function that got the value from a parameter and returns the result.
Ex:
`const WHATSAPP_REGEX = /Whatsapp\.API\./;`
`const ANOTHER_REGEX = /\s/g;`

`const transfromText => (text: string) => text.replace(WHATSAPP_REGEX, '').replace(ANOTHER_REGEX, '');`